# two RegExp pattern in one input Html5

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In a input i want to validate alphabets , numbers and max, min 
  length. 
 I'm showing separate error for both patterns /input should have 
 alphabets , numbers only \  and another one is    /5 to 15 characters 
  only allowed\

```
<input (focusout)="toValidateForm($event)" 
  pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9 -]*$|.{5,15}">
    <p>{{ERR_MSG}}</p>
<button [disabled]="!form.valid">submit</submit>
```

in .ts file

```
  toValidateForm($event) {
  const Regex = new RegExp('^[A-Za-z0-9 -]*$');
  const LengthRegex = new RegExp('.{5,15}');
  if (Regex.exec($event.target.value) == null)) {
  this.ERR_MSG = 'input should have alphabets , numbers only';
   } else if (LengthRegex.exec($event.target.value) == null)) {
   this.ERR_MSG = '5 to 15 characters only allowed';
   }
  }
```

i can show the error messages. but In html the button is always enabled even the input value is not matched to pattern.

Comment: this is not normal html and javascript, is this angular?

Comment: If you have *one* regex to validate with, how would you know which part of it failed to show the appropriate message? It looks like you need something like a validation library so you can use multiple validation rules and the user would see the ones that are broken.

Comment: Your problem is not clear and seems to actually be two different problems. First, I'm not a regex ninja, but I think `|.{5,15}` is useless in this pattern, because the first part will validate even `a`, while if I understand correctly, it shouldn't. Maybe you meant `^[A-Za-z0-9 -]{5,15}`. But then, to the second question, @VLAZ is right, if you want different messages for different patterns, then you'd need to call these different patterns on their own, not as a single one.

Comment: the code is updated now

Comment: `LengthRegex.exec($event.target.value) == null` seems like a roundabout way to just do `$event.target.value.length >= 5 && $event.target.value <=15`

Comment: ok. how to disable the button ? @VLAZ.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `this.ERR_MSG = '';` before "if" construction and use `[disabled]="!ERR_MSG"` or create separate variable to keep validation status and use it in your .html.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not into Angular, so I'll trust and assume the `<button [disabled]="!form.valid">submit</button>` part really works.

To get the `pattern` attribute match only "alphabets" dash and numbers and only of a size comprised between 5 and 15 characters, then from your two regexes, you need to make `^[A-Za-z0-9 -]{5,15}`:

```js
inp.oninput = function toValidateForm($event) {
  const Regex = new RegExp('^[A-Za-z0-9 -]*$');
  const LengthRegex = new RegExp('^.{5,15}$');
  if (Regex.exec($event.target.value) == null) {
    ERR_MSG('input should have alphabets , numbers only');
  } else if (LengthRegex.exec($event.target.value) == null) {
    ERR_MSG('5 to 15 characters only allowed');
  }
  else ERR_MSG('');
}

function ERR_MSG(txt) {
  _error_reporter.textContent = txt;
}
```

```css
#inp:invalid {
  color: red;
}
/* fake the [disabled] attribute... */
#inp:invalid ~ button {
  opacity: 0.3;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#_error_reporter {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<input id="inp" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9 -]{5,15}">
<p id="_error_reporter"></p>
<button>submit</button>
```

Note that you had a few typos in your code, (e.g `</submit>`) but I'll assume they came only when composing the question.